# Using loop->first variable and if statement but still outputs both results

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying to filter my navbar to only show certain nav based on the condition I set.

But somehow, it stills output the nav that I dont't want it to.

```
@foreach($profile as $key => $data)

          @if(Auth::user()->id == $data->alumni_id)
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('alumni/updateProfile') }}">
              Update Profile
              </a>

          @else

            @if ($loop->first)
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('alumni/createNewProfile') }}">
              Update Profile 1
              </a>                             
             @endif

           @endif
@endforeach
```

But somehow in another user account I made, it properly filter the navbar.

So I am actually a little bit confused on what's happening.

[The working one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2peto.jpg)

[The failed one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs5EZ.jpg)

Glad if any of you guys saw anything, thank you!

Comment: Show the output of "$profile" variable

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? If that works using one account, but not the other, why not check for the difference between them?

Comment: Already have the solution, brother. Thank you. @NicoHaase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a logic problem based on the *order* of the loop of profiles.

You are essentially saying that if the **very first profile in the loop** is not an alumni, then display the menu item `Update Profile 1`.  I.E. the `Update Profile 1` is ALWAYS going to display, unless the alumni id is the very first id in the loop.

To correct, here is one possibility of changing your logic around to take this into account:

**Edit based on comment**: if you just want to display a different menu if the `Auth::User` matches the `alumni_id`, take out the `$loop` check and find the match outside of a loop.  (I'll write this out long-ways for understanding - you can combine for efficiency).  Suggest naming `$profiles` as plural - that got me on thinking this through.

```
    $alumni_ids = $profile->pluck('alumni_id')->toArray();

    @if(in_array(Auth::user()->id, $alumni_ids))
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('alumni/updateProfile') }}">
          Update Profile
          </a>

    @else
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('alumni/createNewProfile') }}">
          Create New Profile
          </a>                             

    @endif
```

I'm not sure what your exact intent is in terms of when to display what, but the above should show why it is not working, and give an idea on how to change it to work closer to what you want.

You can also consider changing the check for `alumni_id` to a single `in_array()` or in `collection` check outside the loop to know which you are hunting for - comparing the loop AND the id is what is getting you into trouble.

Comment: What I want to achieve actually is if the `Auth::user()->id` matches the `$data->alumni_id` , display the Update Profile nav. Otherwise, if it doesn't match, display the Update Profile 1 (should renamed it to Create New Profile). Only one nav should be displayed at one time. @Watercayman

Comment: That's no problem, and now we can answer the question without the extra logic issue.  See edited answer.

Comment: That's  the first thing I do when I think of this actually, exactly like what you edited but it still outputs the else condition results. That's what getting me. As if the else does not exist and it continues to iterate the results. :( @Watercayman

Comment: I should have taken my own advice for the last part of my question. Edited now - had to take out the `$data->alumni_id` from the old script.

Comment: It works well! Just need to remove the `== $data->alumni_id` inside the if statement. Thank you very much, good sir! Bless you. @Watercayman

Comment: LOL - I caught that too after I looked at it again.  All set - glad it helped :)